# Trying to dynamically add to an html table from a form using js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to do this by creating an array that stores an object with instance variables relating to input from the form, then append whatever was added from the form to the table. Whenever I call the fucntion to do so nothing happens. I'm not sure exactly where I am going wrong.  I should mention that this is being done using bootstrap 4

```js
var locationList = [];

function locations_addAndSave() {
  var locationForm = document.forms['locations'];
  var city = locationForm.elements['city'].value;
  var opening = locationForm.elements['opening'].value;
  var closing = locationForm.elements['closing'].value;

  var locationData = new Object();
  locationData.city = city;
  locationData.opening = opening;
  locationData.closing = closing;

  locationList.push(locationData);

  var locationHtml = addLocations(locationList);
  var table = document.getElementById("locationTable");
  table.innerHTML = locationHtml;
}

function addLocations(locationList) {

  var newTable = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < locationList.length; i++) {
    newTable += "<tr>";
    newTable += "<td>";
    newTable += locationList[i].city;
    newTable += "</td>";
    newTable += "<td>";
    newTable += locationList[i].opening;
    newTable += "</td>";
    newTable += "<td>";
    newTable += locationList[i].closing;
    newTable += "</td>";
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered" id="locationTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>City</th>
      <th> Opens (AM) </th>
      <th>Closes(PM)</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Calgary</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Edmonton</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ancouver</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>10</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<form action="ignore this" name="locations">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="city">City</label>
    <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="Enter city">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="closing">Opening</label>
    <input type="text" name="opening" placeholder="Enter Opening time 9-11 AM">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Closing</label>
    <input type="text" name="closing" placeholder="Enter Closing time 8-10 PM">
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="locations_addAndSave()">Add Location </button>
</form>
```

```
var locationList = [];

function locations_addAndSave() {
var locationForm = document.forms['locations'];
var city = locationForm.elements['city'].value;
var opening = locationForm.elements['opening'].value;
var closing = locationForm.elements['closing'].value;

var locationData = new Object();
locationData.city = city;
locationData.opening = opening;
locationData.closing = closing;

locationList.push(locationData);

var locationHtml = addLocations(locationList);
var table = document.getElementById("locationTable");
table.appendChild(locationHtml);
}

function addLocations(locationList) {

var newTable = document.createElement('tr');
for (var i = 0; i < locationList.length; i++) {
    var newCell1 = document.createElement('td');
    newCell1.innerText = 'locationlist[i].city';
    newTable.appendChild(newCell1);
    var newCell2 = document.createElement('td');
    newCell2.innerText = 'locationlist[i].opening'
    newTable.appendChild(newCell2);
    var newCell3 = document.createElement('td');
    newCell.innerText = 'locationlist[i].closing';
    newTable.appendChild(newCell3);
}

return newTable;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're building new rows as strings but I have an inkling that without an intermediary like jQuery, you won't be able to properly append that to the DOM.

You can instead do things using the native DOM API like:

```
const newRow = document.createElement('tr');
```

Then you're able to manipulate that row with all the power of the DOM API.

```
newRow.classList.add('some-class');
newRow.style = '...';

const someNewCell = document.createElement('td');
someNewCell.innerText = 'Something!'
```

Then you can put that cell in your new row

```
newRow.appendChild(someNewCell);
```

and you have a real element with your row in it.

then grab your table

```
const yourTable = document.querySelector('#your_table');
yourTable.appendChild(newRow);
```

Your table should now have a new row added at the end.

When you start to have to sort them it becomes a little bit more challenging, but still doable

Comment: Okay, for the sake of this question. Would the ablove edit work?

Answer (score 0):

You missed the operator '+' in your js code

```
var locationHtml = addLocations(locationList);
var table = document.getElementById("locationTable");
table.innerHTML += locationHtml; //here
```

you also can use es6 [String Interpolation](http://es6-features.org/#StringInterpolation) here instead of those lines:

```
newTable += "<tr>";
newTable += "<td>";
newTable += locationList[i].city;
newTable += "</td>";
newTable += "<td>";
newTable += locationList[i].opening;
newTable += "</td>";
newTable += "<td>";
newTable += locationList[i].closing;
newTable += "</td>";
```

write this line:

```
newTable += `<tr><td>${locationList[i].city}</td><td>${locationList[i].opening}</td><td>${locationList[i].closing}</td></tr>`;
```

Answer (score 0):

You also follow one of the below way to achieve your functionality using jquery.

```js
var locationList = [];

$( "#locations" ).submit(function( e ) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  var city = $("input[name='city']").val();
  var opening = $("input[name='opening']").val();
  var closing = $("input[name='closing']").val();
  
  var html = '<tr><td>'+city+'</td><td>'+opening+'</td><td>'+closing+'</td></tr>';
  
  $('#locationTable tbody').append(html);
  $('#locations')[0].reset();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered" id="locationTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>City</th>
      <th> Opens (AM) </th>
      <th>Closes(PM)</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Calgary</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Edmonton</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ancouver</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>10</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<form name="locations" id="locations">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="city">City</label>
    <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="Enter city">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="closing">Opening</label>
    <input type="text" name="opening" placeholder="Enter Opening time 9-11 AM">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Closing</label>
    <input type="text" name="closing" placeholder="Enter Closing time 8-10 PM">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Add Location">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated your code please check

```js
var locationList = [];

function locations_addAndSave() {
  var locationForm = document.forms['locations'];
  var city = locationForm.elements['city'].value;
  var opening = locationForm.elements['opening'].value;
  var closing = locationForm.elements['closing'].value;

  var locationData = new Object();
  locationData.city = city;
  locationData.opening = opening;
  locationData.closing = closing;

  locationList.push(locationData);

  var locationHtml = addLocations(locationList);
  var table = document.getElementById("locationTable");
  table.innerHTML += locationHtml;
}

function addLocations(locationList) {

  var newTable = "";
  

  for (var i = 0; i < locationList.length; i++) {
    newTable += "<tr>";
    newTable += "<td>";
    newTable += locationList[i].city;
    newTable += "</td>";
    newTable += "<td>";
    newTable += locationList[i].opening;
    newTable += "</td>";
    newTable += "<td>";
    newTable += locationList[i].closing;
    newTable += "</td>";
  }
  return newTable;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered" id="locationTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>City</th>
      <th> Opens (AM) </th>
      <th>Closes(PM)</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Calgary</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Edmonton</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ancouver</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>10</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<form action="ignore this" name="locations">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="city">City</label>
    <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="Enter city">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="closing">Opening</label>
    <input type="text" name="opening" placeholder="Enter Opening time 9-11 AM">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Closing</label>
    <input type="text" name="closing" placeholder="Enter Closing time 8-10 PM">
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="locations_addAndSave()">Add Location </button>
</form>
```

Comment: I added return statement in addLocations function and added "+" in table.innerHTML += locationHtml;